# Magento 2: Programmatically Add a Value to `core_config_data`

Tags: php, magento2, configuration, core-config-data

Does Magento 2 have a high level abstraction that allows end-user-programmers to update configuration values in the `core_config_data` table?  Or is using straight SQL the only way to do this in Magento 2?

i.e. in Magento 1, you could do something like this

```
$config_model = new Mage_Core_Model_Config();
$config_model->saveConfig('my/config/path', $unique_id, 'default', 0);
```

and save configuration values into `core_config_data`.  Is there an equivalent in Magento 2?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is the same `saveConfig` method: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.0/app/code/Magento/Config/Model/ResourceModel/Config.php#L26-L61

A usage example from the core: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.0/app/code/Magento/Payment/Observer/UpdateOrderStatusForPaymentMethodsObserver.php#L59-L64

Comment: +1 Useful, thank you!  I'm going to leave the question open for a while to see if an `@api` marked answers bubble up to the top.

Comment: It does change the value in the database but it doesn't reflect on the config page UI

Comment: @coinhndp clear your config cache

Answer (score 27):

I wouldn't use a model or a resource model, but `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface` or `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigResource\ConfigInterface` (the first delegating to the second).

Pretty straight-forward, too:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface;

class SomeClass {

    public function __construct(WriterInterface $configWriter)
    {
        $configWriter->save('some/config/path', 'some value');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the better approach/high level abstraction we should be using. Because 
`\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface` is implemented by `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\Writer` which in turn uses `\Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `\Magento\Config\Model\Config::save`. Below a simple sample:

```
$configData = [
    'section' => 'MY_SECTION',
    'website' => null,
    'store'   => null,
    'groups'  => [
        'MY_GROUP' => [
            'fields' => [
                'MY_FIELD' => [
                    'value' => $myValue,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

// $this->configFactory --> \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Factory
/** @var \Magento\Config\Model\Config $configModel */
$configModel = $this->configFactory->create(['data' => $configData]);
$configModel->save();
```

This syntax is not "simple", but it's more safe for some case.
Du to the save logic, the action might be slower than direct access to the db.

In my case, `$value` need to be encrypted. In `system.xml`, I set the backend model for the field, and the save logic encrypt the data.

Edit: `\Magento\Config\Model\Config::setDataByPath` more simple to use

Answer (score 5):

For a high level abstraction I'd inject `Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface` into the constructor of a data setup script:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface; 

public function __construct(WriterInterface $configWriter) {...}
```

Then use the `save()` method, for example:

```
$website = $this->websiteRepository->get('main_website'); // inject Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteRepository;

$this->configWriter->save('general/country/default', 'US', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITES, $website->getId()); // inject Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
```

Notes:
Use the plural form of scopes: websites / stores in `Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface`

Answer (score 0):

Here a complete sample to handle Magento 2 configuration programatically.

In my case, i add to clear cache too, **else changes does not appear in Store > Config**.

```php
/**
 * @var \Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config
 */
protected $resourceConfig;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface
 */
protected $cacheTypeList;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config $resourceConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
) {
    $this->resourceConfig = $resourceConfig;
    $this->cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
}

public function process()
{
    $this->resourceConfig->saveConfig(
        'my/config/path',
        $unique_id,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_DEFAULT,
        0
    );
     $this->cacheTypeList->cleanType(\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config::TYPE_IDENTIFIER);
}
```

Comment: I clear the cache like your code but it still doesn't show

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7.4 (Support ended Jan 2023)

```
private $configWriter;

private $reinitableConfig;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $configWriter,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ReinitableConfigInterface $reinitableConfig,
) {
    $this->configWriter = $configWriter;
    $this->reinitableConfig = $reinitableConfig;
}

public function apply(): void
{
    $this->configWriter->save(PageHelper::XML_PATH_HOME_PAGE, 'homepage');
    $this->reinitableConfig->reinit();

    // your actions with not-yet initialized updated config goes here
}
```

PHP 8.1

```
public function __construct(
    private readonly \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $configWriter,
    private readonly \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ReinitableConfigInterface $reinitableConfig,
) {}

public function apply(): void
{
    $this->configWriter->save(PageHelper::XML_PATH_HOME_PAGE, 'homepage');
    $this->reinitableConfig->reinit();

    // your actions with not-yet initialized updated config goes here
}
```

Comment: Note : This syntax is supported from PHP8.1 and above (so Magento 2.4.4 and abode). For older version you will need to adapt this a bit.