# Is there a way to save value in core config data using Magento 2 using object manager?

Tags: magento2, database, object-manager, core-config-data

Is there a way to save the value in core config data using object manager like I will get the value by using

I will get the value by

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$configval = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('order/order_settings/date');
$valuesa = (array)json_decode($configval, true);
```

But how will I save these values in the database?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please refer the below link:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92919/32047

Comment: @ChandreshP. Thanks for your links can you please provide me any example for the same.

Comment: You need try the code and check for your case need

Comment: I have tried this but it didn't work out for me

$objectManager->set('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->setValue('order/order_settings/excludedatesvalues', 'as', $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeId = 0);

Comment: @ChandreshP. can you please check

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a model or a resource model, but

> \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface

or

> \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigResource\ConfigInterface

(the first delegating to the second).

Pretty straight-forward, too:
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface;

```
class SomeClass {

    public function __construct(WriterInterface $configWriter)
    {
        $configWriter->save('some/config/path', 'some value');
    }
}
```